# Combine two json responses and filter by objects

Tags: php, json

I want to combine two json from 2 different endpoints. My first endpoint return as array1

```
$array1 ='[
    {
        "id": "410",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor",        
        "featured": null
    },
    {
        "id": "411",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor",
        "featured": null
    },
    {
        "id": "412",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor",
        "featured": null
    }
]';
```

And the second endpoint return  as array2

```
    $array2 = '[
    {
        "id": "410",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor",
        "contents": "Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor",
        "status": "publish",
        "featured": null
    },
    {
        "id": "411",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor",
        "contents": "Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor",
        "status": "draft",
        "featured": null
    },
    {
        "id": "412",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor",
        "contents": "Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor",
        "status": "publish",
        "featured": null
    },
    {
        "id": "413",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor",
        "contents": "Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor",
        "status": "draft",
        "featured": null
    },
        {
        "id": "414",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor",
        "contents": "Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor",
        "status": "draft",
        "featured": null
    }
]';
```

After this 2 resnponses combined in one array, I need to filter based on status, my php script below doesn't return the result as expected:

```
$array1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$array2 = json_decode($json2, true);

$status_filter = 'publish';

foreach ($array2 as $value) {
  $id = $value['id'];
  $status = $value['status'];
  $key = array_search($id, array_column($array1, 'id'));
  
  $key2 = array_search($status, array_column($array1, 'status'));
  
  if (isset($array1[$key]) && isset($array1[$key]['description'])) {
    $array1[$key]['contents'] = $value['contents'];
    $array1[$key]['status'] = $status_filter;
  }
  
}

$json1 = json_encode($array1);
$expected = array_filter($array1, function ($status) use ($status_filter) {
    if (strpos($status['status'],$status_filter) !== false){
        return true;
    }

});

foreach ($expected as $k => $v)
    $output[] = (is_string($k) ? ('"' . $k . '":') : '') . json_encode($v);

echo '[' . implode(',', $output) . ']' . PHP_EOL;
```

within return:

```
[
    {
        "id": "410",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor",
        "status": "publish",        
        "featured": null
    },
    {
        "id": "411",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor",
        "status": "publish",
        "featured": null
    },
    {
        "id": "412",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor",
        "status": "publish",
        "featured": null
    }
]
```

My expected results need to be combining `$array1` and `$array2` then matched within `id` with additional `status` objects to `$array1`. And at the end my expected response for the end users is:

```
[
    {
        "id": "410",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor",
        "status": "publish",        
        "featured": null
    },
    {
        "id": "412",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor",
        "status": "publish",
        "featured": null
    }
]
```

I am stuck at the first response from my php scripts is why the json for the id 411 still return (within the wrong status value).

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Do you control these endpoints? As in, can you change the way they return?

Comment: I am only control the second endpoint. :(

Comment: That should be okay. Could you possibly show us the code you use to generate that endpoint?

Comment: I assume the first endpoint will usually have different values for `featured`, `title`, `description`?

Comment: Yes, the first endpoint always return `featured` as `null` but for `title` and `description` same with the second endpoint. But I need to transform the response to the users who consume this api with `status` and filter for `publish` only :(

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand why you need to combine the 2 arrays if the 1st endpoint always returns the same as the 2nd

Comment: I need to combine this, cause the first endpoint didn't have a `status` in the real application the first endpoint return almost 100 results. within the second endpoint the publish status only have 10 results. That's why I need to filtering this :(

Comment: Hi @GrumpyCrouton what if the first endpoint has different `featured`, `title`, `description` as you mentioned before? what your suggestion if with this condition? thanks for the response my question

Comment: My original idea was to make your 2nd endpoint use the `id` for the key for each set of data, so it's easier to use. I'm not sure how to solve the problem you are facing though.

Comment: I would try your idea, can you please example function?

Comment: No, my idea doesn't really solve your problem. I also don't know how the second endpoint is generated so I can't write any code for you.

Comment: It;s okay, thanks for discussion :)

Answer (score 0):

Given the example arrays this returns the expected output (plus field `contents`). It won't work if `title`, `description`, etc. are not equal in `$array1` and `$array2`.

```
$array1 = json_decode($array1, true);
$array2 = json_decode($array2, true);

$idsToKeep = array_map(function($a) { return $a['id']; }, $array1);

$rowsToKeep = [];

foreach($array2 as $item) {
    if($item['status'] !== 'publish' || !in_array($item['id'], $idsToKeep)) {
        continue;
    }
    $rowsToKeep[] = $item;
}

echo json_encode($rowsToKeep, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo "\n";
```